# Is it possible that there is no verb in a sentence?

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, modal-verb

Is it possible that there is no verb in a sentence?

Take the following sentence as example:

> Morgen muss ich zum Arzt.

Does this sentence make sense?

Comment: Why shouldn't it make sense? Müssen is a verb... nothing is missing. Of course you could say: Morgen muss ich zum Arzt *gehen*, but it is not necessary to do that.

Comment: *muss* is verb enough, isn't it?

Comment: There is a verb in this sentence. It stands there, where all vers stand: At position 2. It is: »muss«, a form of »müssen«.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like in English, there are similar modal verbs (Modalverben) in German. These are *dürfen*, *können*, *mögen*, *müssen*, *sollen* und *wollen*.

Mostly, they are "modelling" the main verb but it is also possible to use them without main verb.

In your example,

> Morgen muss ich zum Arzt

the second word, *muss*, which is the conjugated version of the *müssen*, is the verb of the sentence. Like Torsten wrote in his comment, you could also say

> Morgen muss ich zum Arzt gehen

and in this case, the meaning would be almost same.